# How do I join two anonymous functions together in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How do I if possible join two anonymous functions together so one runs after the other is done?

**My attempt:**

```
    $(function() { 
        $('body').addClass("loading"); 
        function preload(arrayOfImages) {
            $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
                $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
            });
        }

    },
    $(function() { 
        $('body').removeClass("loading"); 
        }); );
```

**The functions:**

```
    $(function() { 
        $('body').addClass("loading"); 
        function preload(arrayOfImages) {
            $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
                $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
            });
        }

    });

    $(function() { 
        $('body').removeClass("loading"); 
        });
```

**JCOLEBRANDS CODE:**

```
   function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $(this[0]).src = this[1];
    });
    $('body').removeClass("loading"); 
}
$(function() { 
    $('body').addClass("loading"); 
})


$(document).ready(function () {     


   var preloadi = [
        ['selector1','WCMSWR/_assets/images/images/1.png'],
        ['selector2','WCMSWR/_assets/images/images/2.png'],
        ['selector3','WCMSWR/_assets/images/images/3.png']
   ];



    preload(preloadi);
});
```

Comment: "My attempt" --- what syntax did you try to follow in your attempt?

Comment: Because the code doesn't seem to be working the way it is currently, and I believe its because of this.

Comment: I've seen named functions continued after each other with a "," I believe my syntax is wrong but you the idea with what I am trying to do.

Comment: can't you just put all the code together into one function?

Comment: So what is the task? You're changing the `src` of the same image multiple times

Comment: I am preloading images as I'm making an interactive guide. I don't want people to have to wait for the images to load for each click.

Comment: Maybe you should try to understand your code (and why it's not working) rather than trying random things that you hope will fix errors you don't understand.

Comment: That was the first step before stack @jahroy

Comment: As soon as you are already using jQuery: https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

Comment: PS: why do you have `$(function() { ` nested into `$(document).ready(function () {     `?

Comment: My whole code is wrapped in the .ready

Comment: @sephiith: yes, but why do you have `$(function() {` nested? Do you understand what it's for? Also have you checked the link I provided 2 comments above?

Comment: @zerkms I have but I don't understand it.

Comment: You should seriously consider taking some time to try to _understand_ the code you're writing.  If you're copy/pasting code that you don't understand, you'll never be able to make changes to it.  Understanding what `$(function())` does in jQuery is a **VERY BASIC** first step that you need to need to take if you're going to use the jQuery library.  It is inconceivable that you would try to make changes to jQuery code without understanding what "_document ready_" means.

Comment: @sephiith: if you understand that -- **WHY** did you nest `$(function() { ` into `$(document).ready(function () { `?

Comment: I have wrapped my whole code in the .ready. Sure the function could be outside but does it change anything being in .ready?

Comment: Yes, you're introducing side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this instead (it's all about the logic):

```
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $(this[0]).src = this[1];
    });
    $('body').removeClass("loading"); 
}
$(function() { 
    $('body').addClass("loading"); 
};
///
/// elsewhere
///

///I'm also updating your array call because it doesn't make much sense, sadly to me
///otherwise you're overwiting all images with the same image every time. 
///I think it makes much more sense to have a set of hidden images in the 
/// footer of the page so the browser keeps them in memory/cache
$(document).ready(function () {
   preload([
        ['selector1','WCMSWR/_assets/images/images/1.png'],
        ['selector2','WCMSWR/_assets/images/images/2.png'],
        ['selector3','WCMSWR/_assets/images/images/3.png']
   ]);
 });
```

So, onload you're adding the loading class, and then once you've finished loading then you're removing the class as the last thing you do.

Ostensibly, however, I would structure it more like this: (assuming a current release [>=1.8] of jQuery)

```
function loadSomeImages(arrayOfImages){
  $.Deferred(function(){

    $('body').addClass("loading"); 

  }).then(function(){

    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
      $(this[0]).src = this[1];
    });

  }).done(function(){

    $('body').removeClass("loading"); 

  }).resolve();
}
///
/// elsewhere
///
$(document).ready(function () {
   preload([
        ['selector1','WCMSWR/_assets/images/images/1.png'],
        ['selector2','WCMSWR/_assets/images/images/2.png'],
        ['selector3','WCMSWR/_assets/images/images/3.png']
   ]);
 });
```

And because you're using deferred's to wait till each thing is done, you're not tying up the jitter (yay IE bugs), your code is clean for what you *intend* to have happen, and you have ordered things to go in the right manner.

Hopefully this did what you basically intended, and helps.

---

I would also urge you to "namespace" your objects. I've extended the previous example to do so below:

```
window.sephiith = window.sephiith | {};
window.sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred = null;
window.sephiith.loadSomeImages = function loadSomeImages(arrayOfImages){
  sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred = $.Deferred(function _startArrayOfImages(){

    $('body').addClass("loading"); 

  });
  sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred.then(function _applyArrayOfImages(){

    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
      $(this[0]).src = this[1];
    });

  });

  sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred.done(function _doneArrayOfImages(){

    $('body').removeClass("loading"); 
    sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred = null;
  });
  return sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred;
}
///
/// elsewhere
///
$(document).ready(function () {
   preload([
        ['selector1','WCMSWR/_assets/images/images/1.png'],
        ['selector2','WCMSWR/_assets/images/images/2.png'],
        ['selector3','WCMSWR/_assets/images/images/3.png']
   ]);
 }).resolve();
```

This namespacing ensures that your code doesn't interfere with "someone else's" code. While it may seem like overkill, over time this namespacing is a good direction to go in. You can also now see if `sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred` has a value in other places in your code, so you can know that you're still loading images, which can be helpful as well. Maybe now you want to do *something else* when this finishes?

```
if(sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred) /* sanity check to make sure we didn't already null it out */ {
  // TODO: track sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred to add a new function #NEWFUNCTION
  sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred.then(function _NEWFUNCTION(){ /* do more stuff here */ });
} else {
  console.log( 'sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred was already nulled out before #NEWFUNCTION!!' );
}
```

so you could build up all these deferred items as the page loads, so that when you hit the `loadSomeImages(things);` you will have all these items fire off before your done.

I realize that `Deferred` may be a big new thing to bite off, so if it doesn't make sense, no worries, but this makes your code much more *intentful* of what you want to have happen. Also notice that I've made sure to tell myself that I wanted to add something else but that `#NEWFUNCTION` didn't get added in time. (also, always name your anonymous functions. It makes stacktrace tracking so much easier.)

So, that last example actually got kind of complicated. I added an HR above it to make it easier to suss out where I "jumped the shark". ***And because I'm an anal dev who wants to make things cleaner as I go ...*** here's some more refinements, hopefully this code progression has made sense:

---

```
window.sephiith = window.sephiith | {};
sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred = null;
sephiith._startArrayOfImages = function _startArrayOfImages(){
    $('body').addClass("loading"); 
};
sephiith._doneArrayOfImages = function _doneArrayOfImages(){

    $('body').removeClass("loading"); 
    sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred = null;
    sephiith._ArrayOfImages = {};
};
sephiith._ArrayOfImages = {};
sephiith._applyArrayOfImages = function _applyArrayOfImages(){

    $(sephiith._ArrayOfImages).each(function(){
      $(this[0]).src = this[1];
    });

};

sephiith.loadSomeImages = function loadSomeImages(arrayOfImages){
  sephiith._ArrayOfImages = arrayOfImages;

  sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred = $.Deferred(sephiith._startArrayOfImages);

  sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred.then(sephiith._applyArrayOfImages);

  sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred.done(sephiith._doneArrayOfImages);
  return sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred;
}
///
/// elsewhere
///
$(document).ready(function () {
   preload([
        ['selector1','WCMSWR/_assets/images/images/1.png'],
        ['selector2','WCMSWR/_assets/images/images/2.png'],
        ['selector3','WCMSWR/_assets/images/images/3.png']
   ]).resolve();
 });

///
/// elsewhere
/// notice we're still loading the page, so we haven't called the onready of the preload
///
if(!sephiith._newFunction) {
  sephiith._newFunction = function _NEWFUNCTION(){ /* do more stuff here */ console.log(sephiith._ArrayOfImages); };
} else {
  console.log('sephiith._newFunction was already defined, not defining again');
}


if(sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred) {
  // TODO: track sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred to add a new function #NEWFUNCTION
  sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred.then(sephiith._newFunction);
} else {
  console.log( 'sephiith.loadSomeImagesDeferred was already nulled out before sephiith._newFunction could be added!!' );
}
```

---

postscript: I didn't test this, I wrote it basically from my workingspace based on what you wanted, and so I may have some bugs, but this should effectively do what you want.

Comment: That is one of the most informative answers I have ever got. I will certainly be referencing this post as I continue to learn jQuery.

I have made a few changes to the top example. But I will endevor to use the ones with namespaces and deferred when I get it working. It may 
be because my image paths are incorrect but should something pop up in console telling me images are being preloaded?

Also because you added selectors, do I need to place those selectors in the code? - Please see updated code above of what I used.

Comment: But you're not waiting while images are loaded are you? What is supposed to `resolve()` the deferred object?

Comment: like I said, I didn't actually refine it :p I meant to add something to resolve it >.<

Comment: @sephiith remember it's all about the _intent_ of what the code should do. I was confused reading your post for a while even while I was typing my answer. Some parts of this answer are highly advanced, and some are fairly simple. Just take the time to understand why you're doing things, don't even execute my code at random.

Comment: @jcolebrand: why do you need Deferred then if you're resolving it immediately? You could just run the code one after another and get the same resuult.

Comment: Any tips for a better structure for posts?

Comment: @zerkms because you may not run it right then. I was just trying to demonstrate how he could make it extensible in other ways, and we didn't dig into that too hard because this is obviously way past his experience level (but causes him to now read up on it) since given the original preload = array in the OP.

Comment: @sephiith I'm going to ask for a new post on that, because I don't understand the context. Do you mean `$.post(url,data,callback)`?

Comment: @jcolebrand: and "how and when to run" is the most important question here

Comment: @zerkms only if he goes the route of using deferreds. The browsers supported may not allow that. Who can know such things? Only the Oracle. All I can do is demonstrate namespacing, deferreds, better isolation of code, statefulness, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put everything in one anonymous function? Call `preload()` as your normally would.

```
$(function() { 
    $('body').addClass("loading"); 

    function preload(arrayOfImages) {
        $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
            $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        });
    }

    $('body').removeClass("loading"); 

});
```

Comment: You don't call the `preload` function

Comment: obviously it's somewhere else. Otherwise the code makes no sense

Comment: It can be called outside the anonymous function, I don't believe this is ALL his script? Or why would it ever work?

Comment: Indeed it's not the whole script, but there is a chance OP wants loader to be shown while images aren't loaded completely.

Comment: It is not the entire script.

Comment: @sephiith: you need to provide more: what and how `preload()` is used for.

Comment: Yes, or else we are just making best guess at what you are trying to accomplish :D.

Comment: @sephiith: explain it yourself in the question. The current implementation changes `src` of the **SAME** image multiple times. Which is odd.

Comment: Agreed, I believe you're missing the index variable from your `.each()` function. Also, please inform us of how `preload()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
    var preload = [
           'WCMSWR/_assets/images/images/1.png',
           'WCMSWR/_assets/images/images/2.png',
           'WCMSWR/_assets/images/images/3.png'
    ];

    function preload(arrayOfImages) {
        $('body').addClass("loading");
        $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
            $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        });
        $('body').removeClass("loading");
    }

    preload(preload);
});
```

Comment: "presumably you would call `preload` here" --- presumably it's asynchronous :-)

Comment: No, the `preload` function as written is not asynchronous.

Comment: `$('<img/>')[0].src` changes image's `src` attribute which triggers asynchronous image loading. M?

Comment: I have tested the above code. It doesn't seem to be preloading the images. I have added the new code to the post.

Comment: @tymeJV: you've edited another guy's answer lol ) PS: no, it won't work

Comment: I'm getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function (LINE 17) Line 17 is: 
    preload(preload);

Comment: So, you can't call a variable and a function the same name on the same namespace ... this `preload(preload);` doesn't work.